# TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['bool', 'str']

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, data-preprocessing

I'm trying to encode categorical variables, but I'm getting this error:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
packages\sklearn\utils\_encode.py:173, in _unique_python(values, return_inverse, return_counts)
    171 uniques_set, missing_values = _extract_missing(uniques_set)
--> 173 uniques = sorted(uniques_set)
    174 uniques.extend(missing_values.to_list())

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'bool'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 3
      1 # Optimization of the dummy_model with the train set: input and target data. 
----> 3 dummy_model.fit(X_train_val, y_train_val)

packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:402, in Pipeline.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    376 """Fit the model.
    377 
    378 Fit all the transformers one after the other and transform the
   (...)
    399     Pipeline with fitted steps.
    400 """
    401 fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 402 Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
...
    181     )
    182 ret = (uniques,)
    184 if return_inverse:

TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['bool', 'str']
```

I have a dataframe with the following variables and unique values:

- dlv [nan 'true' 'false']
- os ['true' 'false' nan]
- cc ['true' nan 'false']
- bpk [nan 'true' 'false']
- pr [nan '2' '1' '3' '4']
- tko ['true' nan 'false']
- w [nan 'free' 'no' 'paid' 'None']
- alc ['full_bar' 'None' 'beer_and_wine' nan]
- ct ['true' nan 'false']
- gfk ['false' nan 'true']
- at ['dressy' 'casual' nan 'formal' 'None']
- rsv ['true' 'false' nan]
- gfg ['true' nan 'false']
- tv ['false' 'true' nan]
- nl ['average' nan 'loud' 'very_loud' 'quiet' 'None']

And the preprocessor is:

```py
Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='None')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])
```

How do I handle the `TypeError`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. "I have a dataframe with the following variables and unique values:" Rather than trying to describe the data, **show** data that causes the problem. First, try to remove parts of the data until you have the smallest data you can come up with *that still causes the exact problem you want to ask about*. Then, include *actual runnable code in the post* that creates such a `Dataframe`.

Comment: Avoid having nan in the dataframe, its type is float so string and float cannot be sorted because of different types

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this issue is caused because `nan` values were replaced with the string `"None"`.

Minimal reproducible example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "dlv": [float('nan'), float('nan'), True, True, False, False],
    "pr":  [float('nan'), float('nan'),  1.0,  2.0,   3.0,   4.0],
})

pipe = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value="None"),
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"),
).fit_transform(df)
# TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['bool', 'str']
```

---

### Fix 1: Drop the Imputer

`OneHotEncoder` should encode `nan` values as a feature. Since `dlv` contains `[nan, True, False]` and `pr` contains `[nan, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. Encoding this dataframe produces an output with 3 + 5 = 8 columns representing "*the missing value in a column is a feature.*"

```py
pipe = make_pipeline(
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse_output=False),
).fit_transform(df)
# [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

---

### Fix 2: Handle Typed Columns Separately

Usually we want to handle missing values for different types in different ways. For example: "Age" might be imputed with the mean, while a boolean might be encoded with a default of `False`.

We can handle columns separately with a [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html). Now the columns will contain `[True, False]` and `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, so the output will contain 2 + 5 = 7 columns:

```py
pipe = make_pipeline(
    ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ("bools",  SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value=False), ["dlv"]),
            ("floats", SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value=0.0), ["pr"]),
        ],
        remainder="passthrough",
    ),
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse_output=False),
).fit_transform(df)
# [[1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```